# PHP Form working on one site but not on new site

Tags: php, forms

I have form on one website that works great and returns all info required, however I am using the exact same php and code on a new site and it will just not work, I also have it 2 other sites and it returns to thank you page but I do not get the email, ii got the script from

http://tangledindesign.com/how-to-create-a-contact-form-using-html5-css3-and-php/

and added a drop down menu to it which also works on one site but not the others, any help would be great. This the php.

```
    $body = "From: $name\n Phone Number: $number\n E-Mail: $email\n type:      $type\n Message:\n $message";



    if ($_POST['submit'] && $human == '4') {                 
    if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
      header('Location: thankyou.php');
        exit;
    } else { 
        echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>'; 
} 
} else if ($_POST['submit'] && $human != '4') {
echo '<p>You answered the anti-spam question incorrectly!</p>';
}
?>
```

and the anti spam;
     *What is 2+2? (Anti-spam)

Comment: It could be that the files the form is trying to access are in different folders, or the path is different in some way.

Comment: And for the anti-spam i recommend using google's solution https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/index.html

Comment: There is really too little information in your question for us to give any real help but: Do the non working sites have a mail server configured? Have you changed the `$from` email address to a valid address for each individual site?